# Haskell list with tuples

Tags: haskell

```
subject = [("maths",[]),("science",[]),("chemistry",[]),("french",[])]

marks = [("science","john"),("maths","john"),("chemistry","ron"),("maths","ron"),("maths","sam")]
```

> output as

```
[("maths",["john","ron","sam"]),("science",["john"]),("chemistry",["ron"]),("french",[])]
```

my attempt:

```
nlist =  foldl'(\ (subjectname,studentname) (x,y) ->
                    if(x `elem` subjectname)
                        then (subjectname,studentname++[y])
                    else (subjectname,studentname)   ) subject marks
```

can anyone tell me what im doing wrong here. I'm getting error: parse error on input nlist

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Also include the error message if you get one, or the expected and actual result if they differ.

Comment: Are you sure that *parse error on input nlist* is the error that you get? That's not the compiler error I get when I attempt to define those expressions in GHCi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write out the types! Here's an example of how I'd use types to construct the program. After that I'll show you how you can use types to fix your own program.

```
type Subject = String
type Person = String

insertOne :: (Subject, Person) -> [(Subject, [Person])] -> [(Subject, [Person])]

insertMany :: [(Subject, [Person])] -> [(Subject, Person)] -> [(Subject, [Person])]

subject :: [(Subject, [Person])]

marks :: [(Subject, Person)]

nlist = insertMany subject marks
```

Clearly you have already figured out

```
insertMany = foldr insertOne
```

It remains to implement `insertOne`:

```
insertOne (subject, person) =
  map (\(subject',list) -> if subject' == subject
                           then (subject', person:list)
                           else (subject', list))
```

Notice that writing out the types helps you to write a correct program.
To see why your program is not valid, let's try to write out the types:

```
f :: (Subject, [Person]) -> (Subject, Person) -> (Subject, [Person])
f = (\ (subjectname,studentname) (x,y) ->
                if(x `elem` subjectname)
                    then (subjectname,studentname++[y])
                else (subjectname,studentname)   )
```

1. `x elem subjectname` does not make sense, because `subjectname` is not a list of `String`. It should be `x == subjectname`, otherwise this is a fine function!
2. `foldl f` would have type `(Subject, [Person]) -> [(Subject, Person)] -> [(Subject, Person)]`

This program is only capable of updating one subject, e.g.

```
foldl f ("maths",[]) marks == ("maths",["john","ron","sam"])
```

What you need now is to apply this to every subject, via `map`:

```
map (\x -> foldl f x marks) subject == [("maths",["john","ron","sam"]),("science",["john"]),("chemistry",["ron"]),("french",[])]
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that you're passing a list of tuples to a function that expects a single tuple.  What it appears you want to do is:

- Look for an entry matching the subject in the accumulating association list
- Get the list of students already in that subject (Or the empty list if no such association exists)
- Create a new list of students with the current student's name added
- Generate a new association consisting of the subject and the new list of students
- Create a new association list with the new association replacing the old
- Pass the new association list to the next iteration of the fold